# Sonar in Jenkins 2 Pipeline - missing global config

Tags: jenkins, sonarqube, jenkins-pipeline, sonarqube-scan

I try to run sonar tests with maven in my Jenkins pipeline project. The documentations says if the sonar is configured globally and you use the `withSonarQube` step the environment variables with the globally configured sonar properites are injected. So far so good.

http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SCAN/Analyzing+with+SonarQube+Scanner+for+Jenkins#AnalyzingwithSonarQubeScannerforJenkins-AnalyzingwithSonarQubeScannerforMaven

My pipeline config looks like:

```
def stash = '********'
def branch = 'dev'

stage('git') {
    node {
        git branch: branch, credentialsId: 'Buildserver-Private.key', url: stash

    }
}

stage('build') {
    node {
        //....
    }
}

stage('sonar') {
    node {
        withSonarQubeEnv('Sonar') {
           sh 'mvn org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:3.2:sonar'
        } 
    }
}
```

The build fails because the sonar plugin trys to connect to the default h2 database instead of the configured one. If i check the log, there are no sonar properties passed to maven.

```
Injecting SonarQube environment variables using the configuration: Sonar
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] tool
[Pipeline] sh
[***********] Running shell script
+ cd .
+ /var/lib/jenkins/tools/hudson.tasks.Maven_MavenInstallation/Maven_3_3_9/bin/mvn org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:3.2:sonar
[INFO] Scanning for projects...

[...]

[INFO] --- sonar-maven-plugin:3.2:sonar (default-cli) @ *******.project.build ---
[INFO] User cache: /var/lib/jenkins/.sonar/cache
[INFO] SonarQube version: 4.5.6
[INFO] Default locale: "en_US", source code encoding: "UTF-8" (analysis is platform dependent)
12:23:17.971 INFO  - Load global referentials...
12:23:18.071 INFO  - Load global referentials done: 102 ms
12:23:18.102 INFO  - User cache: /var/lib/jenkins/.sonar/cache
12:23:18.109 INFO  - Install plugins
12:23:18.176 INFO  - Install JDBC driver
12:23:18.183 INFO  - Create JDBC datasource for jdbc:h2:tcp://localhost/sonar
```

Why is my config ignored? What does the documentation mean if it says?

> Since version 2.5 of the SonarQube Scanner for Jenkins, there is an
>   official support of Jenkins pipeline. We provide a 'withSonarQubeEnv'
>   block that allow to select the SonarQube server you want to interact
>   with. Connection details you have configured in Jenkins global
>   configuration will be automatically passed to the scanner.

It seems they are not ...

Has anybody an idea what am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using an old version of SonarQube (4.5.6, the previous LTS) that requires to pass DB connection parameters (URL, login, password) to the scanners - which is a security issue. `withSonarQubeEnv` does not propagate those settings in order to fix this flaw.

Since SonarQube 5.2, these parameters are no longer required. So you have to use a version that is more recent. I suggest you to upgrade to the latest LTS version of SonarQube (5.6).